# How to create a WCF client using digest authentication to third-party system

Tags: c#, wcf, digest-authentication

I have been given a wdsl for an external system (not .Net-based), and I have used svcutil to create a client/proxy for it. The external unit requires digest authentication for me to talk to it, and supports both http and https.

A couple of questions:

1. There are no certificates involved. Will using https cause problems in that case?
2. I know I can specify transport level digest authentication like this:

   ```
           var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
           binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
           binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Digest;
   ```

However, how do I go about creating the credentials and using them with my binding/proxy?

I can easily find a lot of information online on creating WCF services, but implementation of clients towards non-.Net based services... not so much.

Thanks for any insight!